# How to show warning if user try to input already existing email address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, forms, record

I am trying to create registration form and when user press button submit, I want to show warning message if user try to use email which is already registered.

Here is my action method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult CreateUser(User newUser)
{
    var isEmailAlreadyExists = _service.GetUsersList()
                                       .Any(x => x.Email == newUser.Email);

    if (isEmailAlreadyExists)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "User with this email already exists");
        ViewBag.IsEmailAlreadyExists = true;
        return View(newUser);
    }

    _service.SaveUser(newUser);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<div class="register-card">
    <h1>Register the new user</h1>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div>
            @Html.Label("FullName", "Enter your full name")
            <input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName" pattern="^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)$" required />
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.Label("Age", "Enter your age")
            <input type="number" id="Age" name="Age" min="16" max="110" required />
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.Label("City", "Enter your city")
            <input type="city" id="City" name="City" required />
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.Label("Email", "Enter your email")

            <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" />
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.Label("PhoneNumber", "Enter your phone number")
            <input type="PhoneNumber" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" pattern="^\+38\d{3}\d{7}$" value="+38" maxlength="13" />
        </div>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>

    }
</div>
```

But than I register a new user with an existing email, it just open Index view witout any warning message.

How can I correctly sent warning message when user try to input already existing email?

Comment: Have you debugged the code that sets `isEmailAlreadyExists` to make sure it's working?

Comment: Hard to say exactly what's causing your issue (case sensitivity? leading/trailing whitespace? `GetUsersList()` not returning the full set?) but in any case I recommend adding a method to your service like `bool CheckUniqueEmail(string emailAddress)` and do the check in a query. For performance reasons, it's inefficient to load the whole table of users just to check if the email is already being used, and it'll probably be easier to debug as well.

Comment: As a side note: be aware that such features can be used by malicious actors to obtain email addresses.

Comment: @stuartd Yes, the data goes to the controller and the if condition is met.
I don't understand how to return the message back to the view

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Thank you, I will cathch your advice.

Comment: @Luke Exactly the record check works, the if statement catches if an existing email has been entered.
And I just need to display a message in the view that such an email already exists.

Comment: How can that be true, while you also say "I register a new user with an existing email, it just creates a new record in the database with the same email."? I don't understand how both statements can be true. The quoted statement confuses the intent of your actual question

Comment: @Luke You're right, I confused you, this is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to show message on view side then you can u do that with help of alert box .
You can also show with the help of sweet alert .
https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/